# Python 3.3.3 IDLE closes on save and new file creation

Tags: python, crash, formatting, usb, python-idle

I've had Python 3.3.3 installed on my computer for nearly a year now and used it very frequently. This morning I have been having trouble with my USB stick with the PY file I was working on (USB stick was unplugged without ejecting it and now it needs formatting followed by some other errors).

So I am forced to use a PY file from a few days ago that I made as a backup. The problem is that I can no longer right click my PY file and "edit with IDLE".

I opened IDLE up separately and that worked.

I tried opening my PY file from IDLE, this opened my file for a brief second then closed.
The opening then closing happens when I try to save a new file in IDLE and when I try to create a new file.

This is rather odd as I have not edited any of the inner workings of my Python for a number of weeks, I've just been editing and running programs. This leads me to believe that it all stems back to my USB problem.

I hope someone can suggest some ideas for me.

Answer (score 1):

***Fixed***

Method used to fix it:

1. Go for dinner.
2. Come back.
3. Fixed.

Seriously though, i restarted my computer, still the same. I left the computer while i showered and had dinner and when i came back and tried again i was able to open IDLE without it crashing. Part 1 Fixed!
The second fix was to change the default program that IDLE opens in, somehow it had changed to PythonIcon or something that i have never seen before. I changed it back to Python Console and the "edit with Idle" returned.
Strange how things change on their own but all is good now, happy coding.
Ben